# How do I add music to media iOS

Tags: ios, mpmediaitem

I would like to distribute some music files with my application.

What is the way to add a media from the application folder to the media library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no way to write to Music Library.

However you can add the files to Bundle and play from there and copy to Document directory. You can't change anything in the Music Library, only read permission is granted for third-party libraries.